# How could I speed up my OpenCL algorithm?

Tags: c, sorting, opencl

I successfully write a sorting algorithm based on OpenCL and C. But I found it executed a little bit slow, how can I change my code to make it much faster?

A section of my code:

```c
size_t local_work_size = ((size_t)array_size > max_work_group_size) ? max_work_group_size : (size_t)array_size;
size_t num_work_groups = (array_size + local_work_size - 1) / local_work_size;
size_t global_work_size = num_work_groups * local_work_size;
    
// half = array_size / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < half; i++)
{
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, even_kernel, 1, NULL, &global_work_size, &local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    check_err(err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel even");
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, odd_kernel, 1, NULL, &global_work_size, &local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    check_err(err, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel odd");
}
```

Here is my OpenCL code:

```cl
__kernel void odd_sort(
    __global int *array, 
    int array_size
    )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    index = index * 2 + 1;

    if (index < (array_size - 1)) {
        if (array[index] > array[index + 1]){
            int tmp = array[index];
            array[index] = array[index + 1];
            array[index + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

__kernel void even_sort(
    __global int *array, 
    int array_size
    )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    index = index * 2;

    if (index < (array_size - 1)) {
        if (array[index] > array[index + 1]) {
            int tmp = array[index];
            array[index] = array[index + 1];
            array[index + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are the constraints/objectives here? Why are you using odd-even sort?

Odd-even sort is only particularly efficient if the data set is already mostly sorted, and if your implementation actually detects an already-sorted data set.

What is the nature of your data set? (Size of the set and expectation of ordering already present in the set; range and distribution of values; expectation of frequency of duplicates, etc.) This should influence your choice of algorithm. Even for a mostly-sorted data set, you can probably do better than entirely unmodified odd-even sort.

If you really *must* use pure odd-even sort:

- This implementation does not terminate early when fully sorted, so assuming you're expecting a mostly-sorted data set, this is probably something you should fix. Currently you are always performing the worst-case **O(n²)** operations.
- Half your work-items do nothing because the `if (index < (array_size - 1))` check will fail. Your global size should be half the array size in the even case or half the array size minus 1 in the odd case.
- You don't seem to be making any use of local memory, so why the use of work groups? This could be slowing things down because of false scheduling dependencies. (Implementing an efficient early-out if fully sorted will probably require use of local memory. Don't assume the largest possible workgroup size will be the most efficient, however.)
- You are most likely heavily limited by memory throughput. Only read each array element once in your kernels. Don't rely on the compiler optimising this out.